# QTKit video playback gives screen garbage with ofxQTKitVideoPlayer

Tags: macos, video, qtkit, openframeworks

I've downloaded [this example](https://github.com/Flightphase/ofxQTKitVideoPlayer). It compiles fine and runs but gives this:

http://charliewilliams.org/images/screengarbage.png

It would seem that something's not clearing a screen buffer? I'm using the included .mov file and [openFrameworks](http://openframeworks.cc) 0062 and 007 give the same result.

Comment: Can you confirm that other examples of OF playing MOV files (moviePlayerExample) run fine?

Comment: It seems that it's related to the pixel mode: `OFXQTVIDEOPLAYER_MODE_TEXTURE_ONLY` works, `OFXQTVIDEOPLAYER_MODE_PIXELS_ONLY` and `OFXQTVIDEOPLAYER_MODE_PIXELS_AND_TEXTURE` don't. Of course, I want to manipulate pixels directly (at least, I want to be able to manipulate the alpha channel of the whole image and it seems easiest to do it on a pixel level?) so I'd like to find a way to get one of those pixel modes to work.

Comment: P.S. Implied in the previous answer, but other OF examples run fine. It's only when I start using `QTKit` and changing mode that I get the screen-garbage issue.

Answer (score 0):

it was a programming mistake that cropped up with the new LLVM or Lion compiler changes

should be fixed in the git repo
https://github.com/Flightphase/ofxQTKitVideoPlayer